# Android EditText native selector

Tags: android, android-edittext, selector

I try to apply my own design to edittext and to use android native selector when my edittext is enabled, focused, etc. The problem is that every time I touch the edittext and the native selector is working my edittext becomes smaller. Can anyone please suggest why this is happening?Here is my code snippet:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="true"
    android:drawable="@android:drawable/edit_text"/>
<item 
    android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="false"
    android:drawable="@android:drawable/edit_text"/>
<item 
    android:state_pressed="true" 
    android:drawable="@android:drawable/edit_text"/>
<item 
    android:state_enabled="true" android:state_focused="true" 
    android:drawable="@android:drawable/edit_text"/>
<item 
    android:state_enabled="true" 
    android:drawable="@android:drawable/edit_text"/>
<item 
    android:state_focused="true" 
    android:drawable="@android:drawable/edit_text"/>
<item 
    android:drawable="@drawable/my_border" />
</selector>
```

And here I use my selector:

```
 <EditText 
        android:layout_height="37dip" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="7dip"
        android:background="@layout/selector_input"
        android:paddingLeft="5dip"
        android:paddingRight="5dip"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress">
    </EditText>
```

This is the code of my_border:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/white"/>
    <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="@color/border_green"/>
    <corners android:radius="4dp" /> 
    <padding android:left="1dip" android:top="1dip" android:right="1dip" android:bottom="1dip" />
</shape>
```

P.S. absolutely the same thing is happening with the buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since no one was able to completely answer my question I will answer it by myself. The problem was that my edittext became smaller every time I touched it. That happens because native edittext background in Android has a transparent area around it. So I used a layer list to create my background also with a transparent area around it. Here is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/transparent_background"
        android:top="5dip"
        android:right="5dip"
        android:bottom="5dip"
        android:left="5dip" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/my_border"
        android:top="0dip"
        android:right="0dip"
        android:bottom="0dip"
        android:left="0dip" />
</layer-list>
```

In my selector instead of `my_border` I use this xml.
That's it. Easy to do and hell difficult to find out how!

Answer (score 8):

at first, thanks a lot for your post, helped me alot,
but your code above (sample for selector) wasnt working for me:

so i adapted it for others, so if someone searches **howto mark a textfield as selected**:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="true"
android:drawable="@drawable/bottom_line_normal"/>
<item 
android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="false"
android:drawable="@drawable/bottom_line_normal"/>
<item 
android:state_pressed="true" 
android:drawable="@drawable/bottom_line_focus"/>
<item 
android:state_enabled="true" android:state_focused="true" 
android:drawable="@drawable/bottom_line_focus"/>
<item 
android:state_enabled="true" 
android:drawable="@drawable/bottom_line_normal"/>
<item 
android:state_focused="true" 
android:drawable="@drawable/bottom_line_focus"/>
<item 
android:drawable="@drawable/bottom_line_normal"/>
</selector>
```

**have fun :=) good luck :)**

Answer (score 0):

```
<item 
android:drawable="@drawablemy_border" />
```

1. are you missing a slash [/]? And what is the definition of that drawable `my_border`

Comment: No. I just missed the / while writing my question. Added it already.

Comment: It is a shape with green narrow border all around EditText. I've added the code to my question.

Comment: seems like the border is accepted to your layout after you have focus on it. sou you will have to create your own selector, because by default the android:edit_text does not contain the border. [this link](http://www.androidworks.com/changing-the-android-edittext-ui-widget) might be useful

Comment: The border isn't a problem. It's fine without any border when selected. The problem is that my EditText actually becomes smaller when focused or selected than it is.

Comment: the selector does not cover all cases for the EditText state. What happen if you add `<item 
    android:state_pressed="false" 
    android:drawable="@android:drawable/edit_text"/>` to your selector?

Comment: I've apparently missed the state, but that's not the cause of my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after I tried this files, the EditText doesn't use your selector when it's not enabled and appear with it's standard layout... so adding

`<item 
    android:state_enabled="false"
    android:drawable="@android:drawable/edit_text"/>`
to your selector should be the solution

Comment: I think you didn't get the problem. It's okay if one state works wrong, there's no problem to fix it. The problem is that every time I touch or select my edittext it gets smaller.

Comment: well, I tried this on emulator and device (htc dhd) and the edittext is the same size with or without the selector - it just appear smaller than the standard. If I touch or select it. I really don't get the problem...